# SSLHandshakeException when multiple ssl connections

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I wrote a module that connects to service over https with authentication. After setting proper path to keystore it works fine. There is a problem when I want to use that module (as a jar) in my Tomcat application. I set proper paths (absolute paths) to keystore as well but when I try to connect I get handshake exception

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

As I remember I got this message before when I had incorrect keystore. Do I need to do anything more with that to make it work under Tomcat. Any other issue I missed?
I connect to another service over https without authentication and this works fine (in Tomcat app).

edit: The problem was to run a project that connects to different services through ssl (not only in Tomcat). One with authentication, second without. So I edited the title

Comment: Is this error on the client side, or in your tomcat logs? This error is usually seen client side when you don't have the servers certificate (or one of it's parent certs) in the clients truststore

Comment: Where and how did you configure your trust store?

Comment: your answer seems to fit, you should accept it (so this question is marked as resolved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again I'm giving answer to myself.
After reading [How to control SSLContext scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025525/how-to-control-sslcontext-scope) I decided to do the same and it works fine. By default I don't set any trustStore (so default cacerts is used) and when I need to authenticate I use

```
httpsUrlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLContext().getSocketFactory());
```

when getSSLContext() returns what I wrote above (without setDefault)

I would like to know how to change default SSLContext in Tomcat app so if anyone could help I would be thankful

Comment: This is not a forum, but a Q&A site. Try to have at most one answer to a question. If you've tried something new, edit your question instead of adding more details in answers to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

[Setting multiple truststore on the same JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591281/setting-multiple-truststore-on-the-same-jvm) gave me an answer. I needed only to set my key factory as well as trust factory and it works :)

System.setProperty doesn't set ssl property that is already set.

```
    // load your key store as a stream and initialize a KeyStore
    InputStream trustStream = new FileInputStream("Resources/keystore.ImportKey");
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

    // if your store is password protected then declare it (it can be null however)
    String trustPassword = "changeit";

    // load the stream to your store
    trustStore.load(trustStream, trustPassword.toCharArray());

    // initialize a trust manager factory with the trusted store
    TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustFactory.init(trustStore);

    KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyFactory.init(trustStore, trustPassword.toCharArray());

    // get the trust managers from the factory
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();
    KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();

    // initialize an ssl context to use these managers and set as default
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);
    SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
```

just works fine!